# How to get navController of one tabbar item into another tabbar item

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

In my application, there are 5 tabbar items. When I am in 2nd tabbar item and I perform some operation in that tab, I have to get controller of 1st tab, so that I will be in the 1st tab. How might I achieve this?

Comment: Can you please provide more details on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

write in method `viewWillAppear` of second tab bar

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    FirstViewController *firstView = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:firstView animated:YES];
    [firstView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not quite get your question but here's how you access the Controller of the first tabbaritem - [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need change the tabbar item you selected with code? try:

```
UITabBarController* main_tab_bar_controller = (UITabBarController*)self.window.rootViewController;
main_tab_bar_controller.selectedIndex = 0;
```